# AFNetworking querying server, but not calling any completion blocks?

Tags: afnetworking

This is strange. I have some code that I cut-n-pasted from the AFNetworking readme and started to integrate with my project. So far it looks like this:

```
-(void) retrieveProjectsWithSuccess:(SPERetrieveProjectsSuccess) successBlock
                            failure:(SPERetrieveFailure) errorBlock {
    [_manager GET:[_baseURL absoluteString]
       parameters:nil
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
              successBlock([NSSet set]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        errorBlock(error);
    }];
}
```

`_manager` is previously set:

```
_manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
```

When I call this code from a unit test, the request goes to the server which responds as expected, but neither the success or failure blocks are called.

I've traced the execution into the AFNetworking `AFURLConnectionOperation` class. Everything appears to be correct, all settings and blocks are setup and the request looks good. Putting breakpoints on all the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` delegate callbacks I see `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` and `connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:` called, then nothing. No other delegate methods are called.

Does anyone have any idea whats going wrong?

I've successfully accessed the server from my REST clients and it's working and I see it logs messages telling me it's replied to the request from the app code.

My unit test is use a `XCTestExpectation` which is fulfilled in the success and error blocks, and the test is timing out waiting for AFNetworking to reply.

Really strange.